# How to set a free variable with lp_solve and Java wrapper

Tags: java, linear-programming, lpsolve

I do not understand how to set free variables in a LP problem that I am trying to solve with lp_solve and the Java wrapper.

I use the method

> public void **setUnbounded**(int colnr)
>                     throws LpSolveException

that from javadocs should "set if the variable is free".

However when I call it before solving the LP I get the error

```
lpsolve.LpSolveException: ERROR in set_unbounded: status = -1 (Model has not been optimized)
```

Any clues on what does "Model has not been optimized" mean? If I am not mistaken I should set the free variables *before* solving the LP. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. I was trying to set the column #0 which corresponds to the value of the objective function. The mistake was due to the fact that by printing the LP (with printLp()) the column #0 was hidden for clarity.